# D switch optimization possibilities (DLang)

Tags: switch-statement, d, compiler-optimization

In a D compiler, what additional optimization possibilities, if any, does the “`final switch`” construct give over and above ordinary `switch` in D? (DLang)

Answer (score 7):

**Short answer:** None.

**Long answer:**
The primary advantage of `final switch` over `switch` is that when you use it with a value of an enum type, it gives you an error when you're missing one of the enum members, so you can be sure that you have them all covered. And if the enum changes such that it has more members or fewer, you'll know that you need to update your `switch` statement.

Aside from that, semantically, a `final switch` is pretty much the same thing as a `switch` statement with a `default` case that has `assert(0)` - it's just that it throws a `SwitchError` rather than asserting `0`. The effect is essentially the same though - your program dies when the `switch` statement is given a value that's not covered by any of the cases.

The only reason I can really think of to use `final switch` with anything other than an enum is so that you don't have to write the `default` case when the `case` statements are supposed to cover all of the possible cases. And considering that at least some of the time, you could provide a more meaningful message with an assertion than a `SwitchError` gives you (`No appropriate switch clause found`), I'd be inclined to argue that it would be better to have an explicit `default` case with an `assert(0)` and a message than to use a `final switch` when the `switch` statement is not operating on an enum.

Now, as to your question about optimizations, I don't think that there's any chance that `final switch` provides any optimizations over a normal `switch`. In order to throw a `SwitchError` when the `final switch` is given a value that's not covered by any of the `case` statements, the `final switch` would have to be lowered to a normal `switch` statement with a `default` case that throws a `SwitchError`.

So, in terms of the resulting code, there's really no difference between a `final switch` and a normal `switch` that has a `default` case that throws a `SwitchError`, and optimization-wise, `final switch` is in a similar boat to a `switch` statement with a `default` case that asserts `0` (though `assert(0)` is probably more likely to result in an optimization than throwing a `SwitchError`, because the compiler can assume that the program will die when an assertion is explicitly `false`, whereas a program *could* catch an `Error` and continue, even if it shouldn't).

I don't know whether the compiler can do any optimizations based on the guarantee that the `default` case will kill the program if it's ever hit. If it can, then there may be some optimization that can be garnered by using `final switch`, but a regular `switch` with a `default` case that asserted `0` or threw an `Error` would be in the same boat as `final switch`. So, there's nothing magical about `final switch` in that respect. The magic of `final switch` is in catching bugs with enums.

Really, I'd suggest that you only use `final switch` when you're dealing with an enum type with a fixed set of values so that you can catch when the cases don't match the enum members and that aside from that, you just don't use `final switch`. Honestly, I was surprised to find out that `final switch` accepted anything other than enums.

Comment: The SwitchError is not thrown in release mode (here's a discussion about that: https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11051). Without the checks some optimizations are possible, see for example https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49054 and https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51513

Answer (score 1):

Looking to the `final switch` docs: http://dlang.org/spec/statement.html#FinalSwitchStatement it's just allowing the same optimisations as `switch` in C (it should set labels in code and just use something like goto basing on the variable value). `switch` in D is more general than `switch` in C and does not allow such optimisation. The switch from D can use runtime initialised case values.

Comment: I should have explained myself properly, I didn't mean to compare D with C, though that's a good point, I meant to compare the D `final switch` and `switch` statements’ optimization possibilities in terms of code generation. (Original post later edited to clarify.)

Comment: I just compared `final switch` and `switch` from D with `switch` from C. The `switch` from D can use runtime initialised case values, so I think it cannot be implemented via labels/goto.

Comment: I believe that GDC is intelligent enough to discover all the optimizations that are possible when D code for a `switch` happens to be no more general than C. For example when there's a large number of dense constant possibilities, then it generates a jump table. But

Comment: But the conditions are complex and multiple `cmp`-plus-branches (not chained jump-to-jump) are highly favoured in x86 over jump tables presumably because of the costs of memory accesses and cold cache.

Comment: perhaps someone could comment on GDC or LDC as it's a while since I looked at this.